# Comparator - overloading the operator <

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, set

I am trying to use the `std::set` to contain a struct of three member variables.

```
 struct blah{
       int  a,b,c;
       bool operator < ( const blah& blo  ) const{
           return ( a < blo.a || (a == blo.a && (b != blo.b || c != blo.c ) ) );
       }
 };
```

But I keep getting an error that my operator < is invalid. What is wrong with my approach?
[image]

```
    struct blah {
           int  a,b,c;
                blah(int aa,int bb,int cc){ a=aa; b=bb; c=cc; }
           bool operator < ( const blah& blo  ) const{
               return ( a < blo.a 
                              || (a == blo.a && b < blo.b  )
                              || (a == blo.a && b == blo.b && c < blo.c  ) 
                      );
           }
     };

    int main() {
            std::set<blah> st;

            st.insert(blah(1,2,3));
            st.insert(blah(1,1,1));
            st.insert(blah(1,3,2));
            return 0;
    }
```

After altering the code following @paxdiablo code, this worked well. Thanks y'all!

Comment: Can you post the whole error if FDinoff's answer doesn't work?

Comment: this works: http://ideone.com/rJKFmC

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code as the code you have shown compiles.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is jazzed about posting "it compiles fine" answers. I'm sure it "compiles" on the OP's system too. The error is not a compile error; its a *runtime* debug assertion, most likely because of a detection in a failed strict weak order. See the latter half of paxdiablo's answer below.

Comment: @FDinoff The code compiles quite alright but the the set conatiner doesn't accept the operator. paxdiadblo pointed out an ambiguity in the operator.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind, F'Ola Yinka, though nothing to do with your actual problem: just because you _can_ write a function in one line, doesn't mean you _have to._ I would often rather use something like the commented version in my answer since it will probably be easier for another coder (or even myself in six months time) to understand :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. I was editing the post while you added the commented area. If I'd seen it, I'd probably not posted this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code *compiles* fine for me in the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct blah {
       int  a,b,c;
       bool operator < ( const blah& blo  ) const{
           return ( a < blo.a || (a == blo.a && (b != blo.b || c != blo.c ) ) );
       }
 };

int main (void) {
    blah x, y;
    x.a=2; x.b=2; x.c=2;
    y.a=2; y.b=2; y.c=2;
    if (x < y) std::cout << "x<y\n";
    if (y < x) std::cout << "x>y\n";
    if (!(y < x) && !(x < y)) std::cout << "x=y\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Changing the fields of `x` and `y` outputs different messages.

But I see one major problem with the function. It can tell you that both `x < y` *and* `y < x`, in the situation where the two `a` fields are identical but the `b` fields differ between the two. If you set both `a` fields to 1 and set the `b` fields to `2` and `1`, you see:

```
x<y
y<x
```

That's not going to end well :-)

The fact that what you're getting is a debug assertion (something specifically built to catch runtime errors in mostly debug code) leads me to believe that the runtime libraries may explicitly be checking for incorrect `operator<` overloads by detecting that latter case (ie, both `x < y` *and* `y < x` are true).

You should really fix that because it will cause all sorts of problems with collections where (for example) you need to keep things sorted.

By way of example, let's say you wanted to use `a`, `b` and `c` as keys in that priority. A function to do that would contain something like:

```
// Check primary key.

if (a < blo.a) return true;
if (a > blo.a) return false;

// Primary key equal here, use secondary key.

if (b < blo.b) return true;
if (b > blo.b) return false;

// Primary and secondary keys equal here, use tertiary key.

return (c < blo.c);
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that addresses the ***real*** problem: failing to provide a strict weak order correctly.

Comment: +1 But you can turn the comparator you posted into a one liner. `return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(blo.a, blo.b, blo.c);`

Comment: @Praetorian, that's actually a _very_ good alternative. It keeps the readability while using shorter code. The only possible problem is if you're not using C++11 but hopefully that won't be an issue.